# SIP manager - how to?

Tags: android, sip

I have a very frustrating issue when connecting to sip via Google API (Sip Manager).
My device supports both SIP API and VoIP. The code works ok a lot of times, meaning I get the successful connection to a sip pbx and all works well.
However at times the registration code gets into a "lock" by throwing unhandled exception due to null reference within the sip manager, here's what it says

Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.net.sip.ISipService.open3(android.net.sip.SipProfile, android.app.PendingIntent, android.net.sip.ISipSessionListener)' on a null object reference [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@39fde275

I'm starting to think it may be something to do with the sip stack on the device ..

Any thoughts and advice will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I got the same error. Did you find any solution?